# Testing Faye for message success from Rails app to Faye server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine, faye

I have my main Rails server and a separate Faye server (localhost:9292) setup correctly to handle messaging. Everything is working as expected but I'm having problems with trying to test it.

I'm trying to setup my test as a worker that runs once a day, and if a message isn't received I want to have the app send me an email. Here's what I have so far based on the info in [Faye's docs](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/clients.html)

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'faye/websocket'

class PingFayeServerWorker < BaseWorker

  def initialize

  end

  def process
    EventMachine.run {
      client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:9292/faye')
      client.set_header('Authorization', 'OAuth abcd-1234')

      client.subscribe('/foo') do |message|
        puts message.inspect
      end

      publication = client.publish('/foo', 'text' => 'Hello world')

      publication.callback do
        puts 'Message received by server!'
      end

      publication.errback do |error|
        puts 'There was a problem: ' + error.message
      end
    }
  end
end
```